# How to use a variable one time in Kalman Filter with data in real time

Tags: python, while-loop, real-time, ros, kalman-filter

I have a problem with my Kalman filter. I use Ros in order to receive data from Morse in real time. And, I use the transmitted data to compute a position.

But, in my specific case, I use an initialization step called X_0 and i want to use it only one time. I can't use a while loop in this case to isolate the initialization step because I'am working in real time. Have you got any idea to resolve this problem? I'm a little lost ahah ;)

```
class ListenerVilma:

def __init__(self):
    self.orientation = None
    self.velocity = None
    self.gps = None

def orientation_callback(self, msg):

    self.orientation = msg
    self.compute_stuff()

def velocidade_callback(self, msg):

    self.velocity = msg
    #self.compute_stuff()

def gps_callback(self, msg):

    self.gps = msg
    #self.compute_stuff()


def compute_stuff(self):

# **********************
    # Latitude of the veicule
# **********************

    latitude = self.gps.latitude

# *************************
    # Longitude of the veicule
# ************************ 

    longitude = self.gps.longitude

# *********************
    # wheel orientation 
# *********************

    Orientation_gauche = self.orientation.data[0]

    Orientation_droite = self.orientation.data[1]

    # *****************
    # wheel velocity 
# *****************


    vitesse_avant_gauche = np.sqrt((self.velocity.data[0]*self.velocity.data[0]) + (self.velocity.data[1]*self.velocity.data[1]) + (self.velocity.data[2]*self.velocity.data[2]))

    vitesse_avant_droite = np.sqrt((self.velocity.data[3]*self.velocity.data[3]) + (self.velocity.data[4]*self.velocity.data[4]) + (self.velocity.data[5]*self.velocity.data[5]))

    vitesse_arriere_droite = np.sqrt((self.velocity.data[6]*self.velocity.data[6]) + (self.velocity.data[7]*self.velocity.data[7]) + (self.velocity.data[8]*self.velocity.data[8]))

    vitesse_arriere_gauche = np.sqrt((self.velocity.data[9]*self.velocity.data[9])+ (self.velocity.data[10]*self.velocity.data[10]) + (self.velocity.data[11]*self.velocity.data[11]))



    # *****
# Data
# *****

# Les donnees sont inscrites dans un tableau et elles sont classees
# dans l'ordre suivant:

z_k1 = np.array([[Orientation_gauche],       # rear left wheel orientation
            [Orientation_droite],            # rear right wheel orientation
            [vitesse_arriere_gauche],        # rear left wheel velocity
            [vitesse_arriere_droite],        # rear right wheel velocity
            [vitesse_avant_gauche],          # front left wheel velocity
            [vitesse_avant_droite]])        # front right wheel velocity


#angle

angle_moyen = (z_k1[0]+z_k1[1])/2



# Matrix Q

Q_k1 = np.array([[0.1,0],   # erreur de process pour la distance parcourue     
                [0,0.1]])    # erreur de process pourll'angle ed estarcamento





# Matrix F

F_k1 = np.array([[1,0],       
                [0,1]])

# Matrix R

R_k1 = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],       
                [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],        
                [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],        
                [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],        
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])


# lenght veicule

L = 3.5


# lenght between two wheel

e = 0.375

# Delta t. 

delta_t = 0

# Fréquence d'acquisition de la mesure de distance (ici 1Hz)

f = 1

    #####################################
    # INitialsation step 
#####################################


# I would like to use the matrix P and the variable X_0 only one time>



# MATRIX P. 

P_0 = np.array([[0,0],       
                [0,0]])


# Matrix X 

X_0 = np.array([[0.0000000001],       # Distance      
                [0.0000000001]])       # Angle

# ************************
# ************************
# KALMAN 1
# ************************
# ************************


# ***************
# Prédiction
# ***************        

X_k1_K_1 = np.dot(F_k1,X_0)
X_k1_K_11 = np.dot(F_k1,X_00)

P_k1_K_1 =np.dot(F_k1,np.dot(P_0,np.transpose(F_k1))) + Q_k1
P_k1_K_1 =np.dot(F_k1,np.dot(P_00,np.transpose(F_k1))) + Q_k1


# ***************
# Actualization
# ***************


# Delta t

delta_t = delta_t + f


# Matrice H

H1 = (-L * X_k1_K_1[1])/(X_k1_K_1[0]*X_k1_K_1[0])
H11 = np.asscalar(H1)      # transform array to float 
H2 = L/X_k1_K_1[0]
H12 = np.asscalar(H2)      # transforme array to float 
H3 = 1/delta_t
H4 = -e/delta_t
H5 = 1/delta_t
H6 = e/delta_t
H7 = 1/delta_t
H8 = -e/delta_t
H9 = 1/delta_t
H10 = e/delta_t

H_k1 = np.array([[H11,H12],
                [H3,H4],
                [H5,H6],
                [H7,H8],
                [H9,H10]])


# Matrice z 

Z1 = np.tan(angle_moyen)
Z2 = z_k1[2]
Z2 = np.asscalar(Z2)
Z3 = z_k1[3]
Z3 = np.asscalar(Z3)
Z4 = z_k1[4]*np.cos(z_k1[0])
Z4 = np.asscalar(Z4)
Z5 = z_k1[5]*np.cos(z_k1[1])
Z5 = np.asscalar(Z5)



Z_k1 = np.array([[Z1],       
                [Z2],        
                [Z3],        
                [Z4],        
                [Z5]])


# Calcul de la la matrice K


KA = inv(np.dot(H_k1,np.dot(P_k1_K_1,np.transpose(H_k1)))+R_k1)


K_k1 = np.dot(P_k1_K_1,np.dot(np.transpose(H_k1),KA))



# Calcul de la matrice X


XA = Z_k1 - np.dot(H_k1, X_k1_K_1)


X_k1_K = X_k1_K_1 + np.dot(K_k1,XA)


# Calcul de la matrice P


P_k1_K = P_k1_K_1 - np.dot(K_k1,np.dot(H_k1,P_k1_K_1))



# etape de retour en arrière

X_k1_K[0]=np.asscalar(X_k1_K[0])
X_k1_K[1]=np.asscalar(X_k1_K[1])






X_0 = X_k1_K
P_0 = P_k1_K







if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('listener', anonymous=True)


    ListenerVilma = ListenerVilma()

    rospy.Subscriber('/orientation', Float64MultiArray , ListenerVilma.orientation_callback)
    rospy.Subscriber('/velocidade', Float64MultiArray, ListenerVilma.velocidade_callback)
    rospy.Subscriber('/gps1', NavSatFix, ListenerVilma.gps_callback)

    rospy.spin()
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I love my native tongue as much as the next Frenchie, but you should translate the comments from your code when posting here. Also you're question is not very clear, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask